# Can i flush and then clear em in play framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I need to insert about 70000 records to mysql,but i found it very slow.

So i want to do it this way :

```
if (count % 2000 == 0) {
            QueryResult.em().flush();
            QueryResult.em().clear();
}
```

But when the insertion complete, there's no data really insert into database.

Anyone know about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to commit your transaciton first.

I use the following:

```
JPA.em().getTransaction().commit();
JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();
JPA.em().flush();
JPA.em().clear();
```